# Android widget layout, Android or eclipse bug?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a widget containing a `Button` and `TextView`.  When the `Button` is clicked `Activity1` will be shown and when the `TextView` is clicked `Activity2` will be shown.  Also, when user comes back to home screen, text is added to the `TextView`.

Everything was good until I decided instead to change the buttons and text together and then "BOOM!"

When I changed the widget's `xml` layout, everything was reversed. What I mean is that when user clicks on the `Button`, `Activity2` will be shown, and when `TextView` is clicked , `Activity1` is show.  Even when user comes back to the home screen, the text shows on the `Button`.

I cancelled my changes and everything returned to the first case, except the text was still displayed in the button.  Then I did *Clean & Build* but nothing changed.  Finally, after some tests, I deleted "gen" file and ran the project and this time it was back at the initial state. So I tried to implement the same changes again but hit the same problem.

I would like to change the `Button` and `TextView` together, but I dont know how to do it. Any body has a solution? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Added code

WidgetProvider:

```
public class DictionWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

private RemoteViews views;
private RemoteViews hideViews;

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    System.out.println("Update");

    for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        registeOnClickForElements();
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (App.HIDE_WIDGETS.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        hideWidgetInstances();
    } else if (App.UPDATE_WIDGET_STATIC_TEXT.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String name = "lastWord";
        String lastWord = intent.getExtras().getString(name);
        views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widgetlayout);
        AppWidgetManager mManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(App
                .getContext());
        ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(App.getContext(),
                DictionWidgetProvider.class);
        registeOnClickForElements();
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.widgettextview, lastWord);
        mManager.updateAppWidget(cn, views);
    } else {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }

}

private void hideWidgetInstances() {
    hideViews = new RemoteViews(App.getContext().getPackageName(),
            R.layout.hide);
    AppWidgetManager mManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(App
            .getContext());
    ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(App.getContext(),
            DictionWidgetProvider.class);
    mManager.updateAppWidget(cn, hideViews);
}

private void registeOnClickForElements() {

    views = new RemoteViews(App.getContext().getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widgetlayout);
    // register on click for text view:
    Intent sampleActivityIntent = new Intent(App.getContext(),
            SampleActivity.class);
    sampleActivityIntent.setAction(App.WIDGET_TEXTVIEW_CLICKED);
    PendingIntent sampleActivityPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            App.getContext(), 0, sampleActivityIntent, 0);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgettextview,
            sampleActivityPendingIntent);

    // register on click for "openDictionary" button:
    String category = "requesterFromWidget";
    Intent dictionActivityIntent = new Intent(App.getContext(),
            DictionActivity.class);
    dictionActivityIntent.setAction(App.WIDGET_OPEN_DICTIONARY_CLICKED);
    dictionActivityIntent.addCategory(category);
    PendingIntent dictionActivityPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            App.getContext(), 0, dictionActivityIntent, 0);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.openDictionary,
            dictionActivityPendingIntent);
}

}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/widgettextview"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:text="search" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/speaker"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/openDictionary"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:src="@drawable/splitter" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Andro Selva :I was tested "project -> clean" but did not answer.

Comment: @Andro Selva :please see my edit.

Comment: What changes were you trying to make?

Comment: @Chilledrat :I would to try changing the button(openDictionary) and textview(widgettextview) together.Really I would to set "openDictionary" then "widgettextview" and then "speaker" in widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug and I solved my problem:
I forced my changes,then changed an id of a view in xml layout and did save all(`Ctrl + shift + s` in eclipse).Then again I returned it's value to previous value and  did save all.